# pass list<object> from android to php in json format using URLConnection

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to send 2 variables(mobile_no,group_id) and 1 list of JSONObject with name & number arguments.
Somehow I am able to display mobile_no,group_id in toast but cannot display any value from the list objects. Instead i get some error: PHP Error Message

Here is my code:

```
      private Context context;

public SendJsonObject(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    URL url;
    URLConnection urlConn;
    DataOutputStream printout;

    try {
        url = new URL (php_url);

        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        urlConn.connect();
//Create JSONObject here

        List<JSONObject> mylist=new ArrayList<>();

        JSONObject contacts=new JSONObject();
        contacts.put("name","ABC");
        contacts.put("number","9999999999");
        mylist.add(contacts);


        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        jsonParam.put("mobile_no", "998888888");
        jsonParam.put("group_id", "11");
        jsonParam.put("mylist", mylist);

        printout=new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        printout.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
        printout.flush();
        printout.close();

        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
        String response= reader.readLine();


        String name=response.substring(3);
        return response;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

    Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

}

And this is my php code :

```
<?php

 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $data = json_decode($json, true);

 echo $data['mobile_no'];
 echo $data['group_id'];
 echo $data['mylist'][0]['name']; 

 ?>
```

Please help me on this guys,would really appreciate it .....

Comment: Try using a [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) instead of an ArrayList.

Comment: will try to implement

Comment: Added an answer below to help clarify

Comment: It worked !!! You are a saviour .. thanx alot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the problem is that you are mixing JSON and an ArrayList, which your php knows nothing about. It would be better to use a [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) instead, which is a properly formatted array of JSONObjects. They are very similar to JSONObjects. The basic formatting would be like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject contacts = new JSONObject();
contacts.put("name", "ABC");
contacts.put("number", "9999999999");
jsonArray.put(contacts);
```

Then you can add the JSONArray to your `jsonParam` object and the php should recognize it all as JSON.

---

**RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**

Turning an ArrayList of custom objects into json is very easy using Google's `Gson` library. Here's how you would do it if you had a custom class called `MyUser`:

If you had a class that looked like this...

```
class MyUser {
    String name;
    String location;
}
```

You could turn it into JSON like this...

```
ArrayList<MyUser> users = new ArrayList<>();

MyUser user1 = new MyUser();
user1.name = "stack";
user1.location = "overflow";
users.add(user1);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String usersJson = gson.toJson(users);
//send the usersJson String into your server
```

As you can see, it's only 2 lines of code to turn your ArrayList of custom objects into JSON using Gson. It's insanely simple.

You can find out more about downloading and installing Gson into your project here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Please click the accept button if you feel it helped solve your issue.

Comment: And what if i want to pass list< object> with name and number as parameters of it ..as in a class with name & number as its 2 variables

Comment: The most straightforward way would be to create a JSONArray, then iterate through the List and create a new JSONObject for each object, and add it to the JSONArray, then pass the JSONArray to the server. Another approach would be to use Google's `Gson` library to serialize your ArrayList of custom objects directly into JSON.

Comment: is it possible for u to guide me for Gson through some sample code ..plzz ?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: thanx once again...Is there any way i can directly ping u in case i get stuck later in my apllication ??

Comment: @lionheart - I scan the android topics almost every day, so it would be easiest to just post a new question if you get stuck. That way, your question can benefit the community and my answer (or someone else's) can also benefit the community.

Comment: uhh  @NoChinDeluxe , i tried implementing Gson, but on debug , i observerd that it is adding / to the parameters of the class object , therefore not giving the result..   Something like this                             {"mylist":"[{\"name\":\"ABC\",\"number\":\"8787878\"},{\"name\":\"DEF\",\"number\":\"0909090\"}]","group_id":"11","mobile_no":"84444"}